# How to get select field text from html form in django?

Tags: python, django

I have created a form with select field in template ehrinfo.html

```
<form action="{% url 'ehrs:compcreate' %}" method="GET">
    <select>
        <option value="Vital Signs">Vital Signs</option>
        <option value="Cancer Signs">Cancer Signs</option>
    </select><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Select Template" class="addehr">
</form>
```

I have defined form class as:

```
class templateselect(forms.Form):
CHOICES = (
    ('Vital Signs', 'Vital Signs'),
    ('Cancer Signs', 'Cancer Signs'),
)
template = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=CHOICES)
```

Now I want to get selected text from this form in view compcreate. So I used:

```
def compcreate(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = templateselect(request.GET)
    print("a")
    if form.is_valid():
        print("b")
        template = str(form.cleaned_data["template"])
```

but it cant get past the `if form.is_valid():` part as 'a' is printed but 'b' is not printed on console. What is the problem? How can I get the selected text in compcreate()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to render your form would be to pass it in to your template via the context object and change your template. For example:

```
<form action="{% url 'ehrs:compcreate' %}" method="GET">
    {{ form.as_p }}<br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Select Template" class="addehr">
</form>
```

If you want to stick with your current setup, looking at the html produced by the previous solution suggests that adding a name (equal to the name of your field in the Form class declaration) to your select field should also work:

```
<form action="{% url 'ehrs:compcreate' %}" method="GET">
<select name="template">
    <option value="Vital Signs">Vital Signs</option>
    <option value="Cancer Signs">Cancer Signs</option>
</select><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Select Template" class="addehr">
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach works with ModelForm and POST request:

```
def compcreate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = templateselect(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ts = form.save(commit=False)
            print(ts.template)
```

Let me know if it works in your case.